# obj loader not displaying correctly in c++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an issue with my wavefront .obj loader where it isn't displaying what I want it to display. I want it to display a cube, but I keep getting this:
[image]

Here is my obj file

```
# cube.obj
#

g cube

v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.0 0.0 1.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
v 0.0 1.0 1.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 1.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 1.0

vn 0.0 0.0 1.0
vn 0.0 0.0 -1.0
vn 0.0 1.0 0.0
vn 0.0 -1.0 0.0
vn 1.0 0.0 0.0
vn -1.0 0.0 0.0

f 1//2 7//2 5//2
f 1//2 3//2 7//2
f 1//6 4//6 3//6
f 1//6 2//6 4//6
f 3//3 8//3 7//3
f 3//3 4//3 8//3
f 5//5 7//5 8//5
f 5//5 8//5 6//5
f 1//4 5//4 6//4
f 1//4 6//4 2//4
f 2//1 6//1 8//1
f 2//1 8//1 4//1
```

I added parts in my code to see if everything is being stored correctly, vertices and normals are stored as GLfloats

#### Display:

[image]

#### Inputs:

[image]

Here is my draw function:
I'm not quite sure about the last parameter in glDrawArrays, it is hard coded because I'm not quite sure about the number of indices.

```
void Draw(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,0, vertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (14));

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

This is my main aswell:

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutCreateWindow("Object Loader!");

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    //glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    GLfloat posLight0[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f};
    GLfloat lightColor[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, posLight0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor);

    setUpArrays();

    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
}
```

One last thing is that I am not allowed to use glDrawElements or glBegin() direct mode.

Here is more of my program if it is helpful:
Global variables setup at the beginning

```
GLfloat* vertices;
GLfloat* normals;
GLint* faces;
int amountOfFaces;
double rotate_y=0;
double rotate_x=0;
Loader* loader = new Loader();
```

Setting up the arrays for the vertices, normals and indices:

```
void setUpArrays()
{
    loader->loadObject("cube.obj");


    vector<GLfloat> temp = loader->getVerticies();
    vertices = new GLfloat[temp.size()];
    int tempSize = 0;
    cout << "vectors: ";
    for(vector<GLfloat>::const_iterator i = temp.begin(); i != temp.end(); ++i)
    {
        vertices[tempSize] = *i;
        cout << vertices[tempSize] << ", ";
        tempSize++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    vector<GLfloat> tempNormal = loader->getNormals();
    normals = new GLfloat[tempNormal.size()];
    tempSize = 0;
    cout << "normals: ";
    for(vector<GLfloat>::const_iterator i = tempNormal.begin(); i != tempNormal.end(); ++i)
    {
        normals[tempSize] = *i;
        cout << normals[tempSize] << ", ";
        tempSize++;
    }
    amountOfFaces = tempSize;
    cout << endl;

    vector<GLint> tempIndices = loader->getFaces();
    faces = new GLint[tempIndices.size()];
    tempSize = 0;
    cout << "Indices: ";
    for(vector<GLint>::const_iterator i = tempIndices.begin(); i != tempIndices.end(); ++i)
    {
        faces[tempSize] = *i;
        cout << faces[tempSize] << ", ";
        tempSize++;
    }
    cout << endl;

    amountOfFaces += tempSize;
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't attach the output that you're getting to the question properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm baffled as to why but the OBJ format gives vertex attribute indices starting at 1, and not 0. I.e. `f 1//2` refers to the first vertex and second normal. Your debug output doesn't show a zero in indices so I'm guessing the loader hasn't accounted for this.

> A valid vertex index starts from 1 and matches the corresponding vertex elements of a previously defined vertex list. Each face can contain three or more vertices. [[wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Face_definitions)

Hopefully the fix is as easy as: `faces[tempSize] = *i - 1;`

[*EDIT*]
Your draw call specifies 14 vertices, but you have 12 triangles so should be drawing 36. `amountOfFaces` sounds like it should be `tempIndices.size()/3`.

Your vectors should be references to avoid a copy, and it will be way faster to populate `faces` etc. with a single `memcpy`. E.g: `memcpy(faces, &tempIndices.front(), sizeof(GLint) * tempIndices.size())`

[*EDIT*]
Oh, right, of course. Now I feel silly for not noticing. Faces indexes the vertices, so they can be reused (saves memory and extra processing). Instead of `glDrawArrays` you want this:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces); //replate 36 for things you draw that aren't cubes
```

If you wanted to use `glDrawArrays`, you would have to rearrange your vertex arrays so each vertex appears in the order given by `faces`, including all the duplicates. For example your new position array would be `[0,0,0, 1,1,0 1,0,0 ...]` being vectors 0,6,4 forming the first triangle. `std::vector`s make this kind of rearranging easy to code.

One last thing. The normals array isn't as big as the position array, but OpenGL doesn't support mixed indexing. So you'll have to duplicate some of the normals so every vertex has both a position and normal.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! I managed to get it to draw a cube, it's just that sometimes when I recompile and run, it draws a cube and sometimes it doesn't. Also, with faces[], I actually haven't used it anywhere, I'm still a newbie to openGL and I just wanted to know where I would have to put it. I do know that it is used in glDrawElements, but I am only allowed to use glDrawArrays

Comment: Omg thankyou so much! I managed to get it to display a cube properly! You're a life saver!